# How to install Doxygen on Ubuntu?

Tags: doxygen

I downloaded `doxygen-1.8.20.linux.bin.tar.gz` here: https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html.

How to install it on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @Rinzwind from what do you deduct that only python 2.7 is supported? The software uses for the builds some python, but doxygen itself doesn't need it. furthermore the builds run, to the best of my knowledge with python 2.7 and python 3

Comment: On the download page https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#srcbin you find a version for Ubuntu 20.04. You can download the compressed tar file and place the executable(s) in a directory and when necessary add this directory to your path (e.g. /usr/local/bin). When you would like to compile yourself download the sources, extract the compressed tar file follow the instructions as with the "github clone version" in the build/bin directory you will find the executables

Answer (score 3):

This software is already [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/doxygen) in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS **repository** with modern and actual 1.8.17 version.

Simply open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install doxygen
```

then use it as it was planned.

Comment: The mentioned doxygen version 1.8.17 is not the latest version as the current version is 1.8.20.

Comment: @albert, [how to build the latest version from source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502796/327339).

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded `doxygen-1.8.20.linux.bin.tar.gz` here: https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html.
>
> How to install it on Ubuntu

### Download and install the latest version of `doxygen` and `doxywizard` (the GUI)

For *any* version of Ubuntu:

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.*

Download the latest version here: https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html

...or an older version or the latest version from the official GitHub releases page here: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/releases

Extract the `.tar.gz` file, make it and install it. Assuming the version you want is `doxygen-1.10.0.linux.bin.tar.gz`, the full download, make and install instructions would look like this:

```bash
# Create a directory where you want to download it
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/Install_Files/Doxygen
cd ~/Downloads/Install_Files/Doxygen

# download it
wget https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/releases/download/Release_1_10_0/doxygen-1.10.0.linux.bin.tar.gz

# extract it
tar -xf doxygen-1.10.0.linux.bin.tar.gz

# cd into the extracted directory
# - Note: this directory already has a `bin` dir with prebuilt binary
#   executables. 
cd doxygen-1.10.0

# make and install it
sudo make
sudo make install

# Ensure it's installed
# Example output:
#
#       1.10.0 (ebc57c6dd303a980bd19dd74b8b61c8f3f5180ca)
#
doxygen --version

# Check your man pages available by typing `man doxy` and pressing Tab twice. 
# Output:
#
#       doxygen      doxyindexer  doxysearch   doxywizard  
# 

# View those man pages
man doxygen
man doxyindexer
man doxysearch
man doxywizard
```

The other tools that came with your doxygen download above are available in the `doxygen-1.10.0/bin/` directory which you extracted from the `.tar.gz` file above. Get access to those executables by adding that dir to your `PATH` environment variable. To do that, add the following lines to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
# Add doxygen to the PATH
DIR="$HOME/Downloads/Install_Files/Doxygen/doxygen-1.10.0/bin"
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    PATH="$DIR:$PATH"
fi
```

Now re-source your `~/.bashrc` file to apply the changes, and test the new executables:

```bash
# re-source your ~/.bashrc file
. ~/.bashrc

# Install the libxapian.so.30 shared object library, required by 
# `doxysearch.cgi`
# Note: If you are missing this library and you run `doxysearch.cgi`, you'll
# see this error:
# 
#       doxysearch.cgi: error while loading shared libraries: libxapian.so.30: 
#       cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxapian30

# Test the new doxygen executables from the `doxygen-1.10.0/bin/` dir
doxygen --version  # should be the same as above
doxyindexer --version
doxysearch.cgi --version
doxywizard --version  # opens a GUI popup window with version info.
```

To run the GUI-based doxygen configuration file editor, run `doxywizard` at the command line.

### Install GraphViz

`doxygen` requires GraphViz to generate call graphs and class diagrams via the `dot` utility. So install GraphViz, and the `dot` utility, like this:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install graphviz

# Ensure it is now installed
dot -V  # shows the version
```

### Use the `doxygen` executable

Basic Doxygen usage:

```bash
# Create a new Doxygen configuration file named Doxyfile
doxygen -g Doxyfile
```

Now edit the `Doxyfile` to your liking, either manually or in the GUI `doxywizard` tool by running `doxywizard`.

You can also use the `doxywizard` GUI to create and edit the `Doxyfile` configuration file. Just run `path/to/doxygen-1.10.0/bin/doxywizard` at the command line. See below for more info.

Then, run `doxygen` to generate the documentation (note that `time` just times how long it takes, and is optional):

```bash
time doxygen Doxyfile
```

### Doxyfile configuration

For a lot more info. and recommended settings, see my notes in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here: [Doxygen installation and setup](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/Doxygen).

I also have these files there:

> 1. `Doxyfile_CUSTOMIZED` - my doxygen configuration file with my recommended settings after going through the "Setup and usage" section below.
> 2. `Doxyfile_DEFAULT` - the default doxyfile created by running `doxygen -g Doxyfile`.
> 3. `Doxyfile_run_doxygen.sh` - A script to:
>
>    1. automatically generate Doxygen documentation for a C or C++ project
>    2. store repo info. into a special readme at path `"$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/doxygen_info_README.md"`, next to the doxygen output, and
>    3. open the `index.html` Doxygen output webpage in the Google Chrome web browser.

Comment: I tested these steps just now on Ubuntu 20.04, all run properly, except that "sudo apt install graphviz" was prompted: You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 graphviz : Depends: libann0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcdt5 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcgraph6 but it is not going to be installed... and this would be fixed with "sudo apt --fixe-broken install" not "sudo apt --fixe-broken install praphviz"